# How to create progress bars with css3

Tags: css, progress-bar, css-transitions, css-animations

I am a developer and not a designer so please be easy with me. I am trying to create a list of progress bars but animations are not working on this . What i want to run progress bars to defined width slowly when the page reach on the element position.
Here is my HTML page content

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <!-- Skill Bars -->
            <div class="progress-straight skill-bar ">
                <div class="progress-bar-straight progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <span class="skill">HTML <i class="val">100%</i></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="progress-straight skill-bar">
                <div class="progress-bar-straight progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
                    <span class="skill">CSS<i class="val">90%</i></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="progress-straight skill-bar">
                <div class="progress-bar-straight progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <span class="skill">JavaScript<i class="val">75%</i></span>
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="progress-straight skill-bar">
                <div class="progress-bar-straight progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="55" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <span class="skill">Photoshop<i class="val">55%</i></span>
                </div>
            </div>  

    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is

```
.progress-straight {
  height: 35px;

}
.progress-straight .skill {
  font: normal 12px "Open Sans Web";
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.progress-straight .skill .val {
  float: right;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.progress-bar-straight {
  text-align: left;
  transition-duration: 3s;
 transition: width 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: width 0s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0s ease;
    -ms-transition: width 0s ease;
}
```

Javascript code is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.progress-straight .progress-bar-straight').css("width",
                function() {
                    return $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "%";
                }
        )
    });
</script>
```

I also have a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/r2gqj9Lf/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think it is, why aren't the bars  moving? That's because you haven't set an initial width.

Answer (score -1):

You have kept transition timing as 0s. You need to provide some time to it and an inital width.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.progress-straight .progress-bar-straight').css("width",
                function() {
                    return $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "%";
                }
        )
    });
```

```css
.progress-straight {
  height: 35px;
  background: lightcoral;

}
.progress-straight .skill {
  font: normal 12px "Open Sans Web";
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.progress-straight .skill .val {
  float: right;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.progress-bar-straight {
  text-align: left;
  transition-duration: 3s;
 transition: width 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: width 0s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: width 0s ease;
        background: red;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <!-- Skill Bars -->
            <div class="progress-straight skill-bar ">
                <div class="progress-bar-straight progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:33%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <span class="skill">HTML <i class="val">100%</i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
                
            <div class="progress-straight skill-bar">
                <div class="progress-bar-straight progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width:33%" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >
                    <span class="skill">CSS<i class="val">90%</i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="progress-straight skill-bar">
                <div class="progress-bar-straight progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" style="width:33%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <span class="skill">JavaScript<i class="val">75%</i></span>
                </div>
            </div>  
            
            <div class="progress-straight skill-bar">
                <div class="progress-bar-straight progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width:33%" aria-valuenow="55" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <span class="skill">Photoshop<i class="val">55%</i></span>
                </div>
            </div>  
            
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is your updated fiddle

Comment: I have fixed it for firefox. you can add same for other browsers as well